# Algorithm needed to determine heirarchy of geometric shapes

Tags: c#, algorithm, binary-search-tree

I've been trying without much luck to develop an algorithm to sort a collection of closed geometric figures based on whether one shape is completely enclosed within the perimeter of another.  When completely analyzed, I should end up with a tree structure that defines the hierarchy.

I can take care of the actual comparison, which is whether one shape is completely within the perimeter of another.  I'm having difficulty though with the sorting of unorganized input.  I suspect that the solution involves binary tree structures and recursive code, which I've never been strong with.

Geometric data will have already been sanitized prior to generating the sorted hierarchy data, so issues like open paths, overlapping, partially overlapping and self-intersecting shouldn't be an issue.

Below is a group of test figures I've been working with that may help to illustrate my question.

[image]

As a human, I can see that the yellow shape is not within the blue one, nor is the blue within the yellow.  They are both within the green shape, which is within the red... and so on.  (Apologies to those who are color blind)

The resultant tree would be as follows:

[image]

I'm working in C# but don't figure it's relevant to the question.

Thank you

**EDIT 1**

A more concise question might be "How do I generate this tree with the correct order?" (given data in no particular order).  Is this just your basic textbook "binary search tree insertion" that I'm over-thinking maybe?

**EDIT 2**

Attempting to convert Norlesh's pseudo-code into c# and tie it into my existing code, I ended up with the following:

```
        // Return list of shapes contained within container contour but no other
    private List<NPContour> DirectlyContained(NPContour container, List<NPContour> contours)
    {
        List<NPContour> result = new List<NPContour>();

        foreach (NPContour contour in contours)
        {
            if (container.Contains(contour))
            {
                foreach (NPContour other in contours)
                {
                    if (other.Contains(contour))
                        break;
                    result.Add(contour);
                }
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    // Recursively build tree structure with each node being a list of its children
    private void BuildTree(NPContourTreeNode2 parent, List<NPContour> contours)
    {
        List<NPContour> children = DirectlyContained(parent.Contour, contours);

        if (children.Count > 0)
        {
            // TODO: There's probably a faster or more elegant way to do this but this is clear and good enough for now
            foreach (NPContour child in children)
            {
                contours.Remove(child);
                parent.Children.Add(new NPContourTreeNode2(child));
            }

            foreach (NPContourTreeNode2 child in parent.Children)
            {
                BuildTree(child, contours);
            }
        }
    }
```

... And the calling code ....

```
            List<NPContour> contours = new List<NPContour>();
        List<NPContour> _topLevelContours = new List<NPContour>();
        bool contained = false;

        foreach (NPChain chain in _chains)
        {
            if (chain.Closed)
            {
                NPContour newContour = new NPContour(chain);
                contours.Add(newContour);
            }
        }

        //foreach (NPContour contour in contours)
        for (int i = 0; i < contours.Count(); i++)
        {
            contained = false;
            foreach (NPContour container in contours)
            {
                if (container.Contains(contours[i]))
                {
                    contained = true;
                    continue;
                }
            }
            if (contained == false)
            {
                _topLevelContours.Add(contours[i]);
                contours.Remove(contours[i]);
            }
        }

        foreach (NPContour topLevelContour in _topLevelContours)
        {
            NPContourTreeNode2 topLevelNode = new NPContourTreeNode2(topLevelContour);
            BuildTree(topLevelNode, contours);
        }
```

I'm thinking I must have misinterpreted something in the translation because it isn't working.  I'm going to keep plugging away at it but thought I'd post the code here in hopes someone may help point out my error.

Note that there was a discrepancy in the pseudocode in that `buildTree` didn't return anything, but in the calling code a return value is appended to ... well, I got a bit confused where exactly it was supposed to be going there anyway.  I got the general idea of the example but I think there may have been some important points that were lost on me.

So far in my brief debugging, I seem to get more than one top level shape from the example below (whereas there should only be one) and multiples of the various children (something like 55?).  I hope to be able to give more debugging information later.

Comment: Could you specify the actual problem a bit more? What "sorting"? If determining if A is inside B is no problem, then what stops you from just doing it?

Comment: The data set that I start out with is an unordered list.  Using the example above, "Purple" may be first in the list, followed by "Green".  Comparing the two, "Purple" is indeed contained within "Green".  However, after doing a bunch more comparisons I may see "Yellow" - which complicates things a bit (for me anyway).  So I guess it's more a matter of generating the tree given elements in any order, putting them in the correct place in the tree.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting

Comment: The topological sorting looked like it had promise but given the lack of description and nothing yielded from my own resultant searches I don't have enough to go down that path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some pseudo code that should achieve what your trying to do:

`// return true if shape is enclosed completely inside container 
function contains(container, shape);
// return list of shapes contained within container shape but no other.
function directlyContained(container, shapes) {
    result = []
    for (shape in shapes) {
        if (contains(container, shape)) { 
            // check its not further down hierarchy
            for (other in shapes) {
                if (contains(other, shape)) {
                   break // not the top level container
                }
                result.append(shape)
            }
         }
    }
    return result;
}
// recursively build tree structure with each node being a list of its children
// - removes members of shapes list as they are claimed.
function buildTree(parent, shapes) {
    children = directlyContained(parent, shapes)
    if (children.length > 0) {
       shapes.remove(children);
       parent.append(children);
       for (child in children) { // recall on each child
           buildTree(child, shapes);
       }
    }
}`

`function findTopLevel(shapes) {
   result = []
   // find the one or more top level shapes that are not contained
   for shape in shapes {
      contained = false;
      for (container in shapes) {
          if (contains(container, shape)) {
              contained = true;
              continue;
          }
      }
      if (contained = false) {
           scene.append(shape);
           shapes.remove(shape);
      }
   }
   return result;
}
shapes = <...>;     // list initialized with the unsorted shapes
scene = findTopLevel(shapes);
shapes.remove(scene);
for (top in scene) {
   buildTree(top, shapes);
}`

Comment: Is this something you've used successfully in the past or put together to answer this question?  I have to say I like the simplicity but at the same time it seems like it might not account for all cases.  I do like that you use a regular tree rather than a binary tree.  My data can be represented as a binary tree but nodes having an arbitrary number of children represent the real world much better.

Comment: I just put it together for your benefit :) - as for not accounting for all cases, none come to mind while stepping through it in my head - but that's what testing is for once you have the skeleton of the algorithm up and running.

Comment: See EDIT 2 above please.  Anything you can suggest after seeing how this fits with the rest of my code?

Comment: Does your implementation of contour.Contains(contour) return true or false? (It should be false to avoid problems in the embedded foreach in DirectlyContains).

Comment: Just did some tidy up of the psudo for readability - re-factored some of calling code into new function findTopLevel() and picked up on the mistake you pointed out where I appended the non existent buildTree result... by the way is the problem domain restricted to having a single shape/contour containing all the others or was I correct in my assumption that there could be multiple top levels?

Comment: Yes, there can indeed be multiple top levels.  contour.Contains(contour) returns TRUE if one contains the other.  This is likely the reason I was getting multiples included in the list.  I've gone a bit different direction with the code and got it working quite nicely now.  Your suggestions definitely put me on the right track to a solution so I'm going to accept your answer.  I don't think that posting my own revised code to this question will add to the solution because from a high level I'm doing the same thing.  It just plays nicer with the rest of my code.  Thanks for your help!